# How do I create an enumproperty dropdown menu that shows up in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, workflow

I'm trying to get my addon and its categories and dropdown menus to show up in blender 2.8 like this: [Simple Asset Manager](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/5/4/1/541650d7faa980968fb72df8bba7650e13b619f4.gif) , but can't seem to get anything to show up, I updated some of the code which I haven't posted here to 2.8, and only the tab on the toolshelf shows, not the dropdown or the preview.

```
# Update

def update_category(self, context):
    enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context)


# Drop Down Menu
class Categories(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    mode_options = [
        ("Basic_Elements", "Elements", '', 0),


        ]

    options = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=mode_options,
        description="Select a Category",
        default="Basic_Elements",
        update=update_category
    )


# Generate Previews
def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):

    category = context.scene.transitions_elements.options

    # Icons Directory
    directory = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Icons" + os.sep + category)

    # EnumProperty Callback
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager

    # Get the Preview Collection (defined in register func)
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the Directory for PNG Files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(""):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        # For each image in the directory, load the thumb unless it has already been loaded
        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # Generate a Thumbnail Preview for a File.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)

            if filepath in pcoll:
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", pcoll[filepath].icon_id, i))
            else:
                thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
                enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


#



#####################################################################

# Register
def register():

    global icons


    bpy.types.WindowManager.some_string = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Enter Text")

    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
            name = "Folder Path",
            subtype = 'DIR_PATH',
            default = "")

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
            items = enum_previews_from_directory_items)

    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
    pcoll.my_previews = ()

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll
    bpy.types.Scene.transitions_elements = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=Categories)


# Unregister
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(icons)
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.some_string
    del WindowManager.my_previews

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

    del bpy.types.Scene.transitions_elements


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Could you edit your question to include the relevant portions of the page you linked to? Thank you, and I hope we get get this answered for you.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited my question based on your suggestion.

Comment: Hi. In future if you need to amend your question you can use the [edit] link below it, instead of asking it again.